# location of points in multidimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, neural-networks

There was a problem while writing a neural network to generate images.

In general, I have an n-dimensional space, k points in this space in a certain area, and an area in this space (in this area, the coordinates of the points can take values ​​from 0 to 1). I need to place points in this space in this area like this,
so that they are as far apart as possible from each other and from the boundaries of the region.

Now I need a solution for 49 dimensions and 10 points, but when writing a different neural network, I may need different values ​​for n and k. I need a argoritm
with which it will be possible to find such an arrangement or at least one solution to this problem (area is always a multidimensional cube with a vertex at the origin)

Comment: See [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what I have to do to solve my problem, I don't understand, how I should apply this in multidimensional space

Comment: Initialize the points randomly and apply a constrained gradient based optimizer.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me matimatic decision of this problem (not coding)?

Comment: There's no simple general solution, even in [the two-dimensional case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square).

Comment: On the other hand, you seem to have enough dimensions so that every point can be placed in a corner of the cube, which simplifies the problem significantly.